# showing that limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I need to prove following statement.

> given following
>
> - $0 \leq x_i^n \leq 1$ forall $i,n$ .  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_i^n = x_i$ forall $i$
> - $0 \leq p_{ij} \leq 1$ forall $i,j$ . $\sum_j p_{ij} < \infty$ forall $i$
>
> prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_j p_{ij} x_j^n = \sum_{j} p_{ij} x_j$ forall $i$.

my attempt :

- Since $0 \leq x_i^n \leq 1$ by order limit theorem we have that $0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} x_i^n  = x_i\leq 1$
- Hence we have that $|x_i^n -x_i| \leq 1 $ forall $n, i$ we will use this later
- consider arbitrary $i$
- We need to show that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall n \geq N$  $|\sum_j p_{ij} x_j^n - \sum_j p_{ij} x_j| < \epsilon$
- $|\sum_j p_{ij} x_j^n - \sum_j p_{ij} x_j| = |\sum_j p_{ij} (x_j^n -x_j)| \leq \sum_j p_{ij}|x_j^n - x_j|$ (all numbers are positive countable triangle inequality holds)
- now since $\sum_j p_{ij} < \infty$ $\exists J \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\sum_{J} p_{ij} < \epsilon/2$
- now split the sum $\sum_j p_{ij}|x_j^n - x_j| = \sum_{j}^{J} p_{ij} |x_j^n - x_j| + \sum_{J}^{\infty} p_{ij} |x_j^n -x_j|$
- we will show that each of them can be made less than $\epsilon/2$
- $\sum_J^{\infty} p_{ij} |x_j^n - x_j| \leq \sum_J^{\infty} p_{ij} < \epsilon/2$ (because  $|x_j^n -x_j|\leq 1$)
- $\sum_j^J p_{ij} |x_j^n - x_j| \leq \sum_j^J |x_j^n - x_j| $ (because $p_{ij} \leq 1$)
- now since $\lim x_j^n = x_j$ $\exists N_j$ s.t forall $n \geq N_j$ $|x_j^n - x_j| < \epsilon/2J$
- take $N = \max\{N_1 ,N_2 , ... N_J\}$ then for any $n \geq N$
- then we have that $\sum_j ^J  |x_j^n - x_j| < J. \epsilon/2J < \epsilon/2$
- we are done

can someone verify the proof ?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Of course $J$ depends on $i$ but this doesn't effect the proof.

Comment: .. I'msorry. This doesn't $\textbf{a}$ffect the proof :)

Comment: @PeterMelech can you write answer so that I will accept

Comment: Of course. I will edit an answer.

Comment: Notice that for all $i$, $x_i=0\lor x_i=1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry I didn't get what you are saying. can you please elaborate

Comment: $x_i$ can only be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ooh.No No. I think I didn't be careful with notation $(x_i^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is sequence.$x_i$ is there limit. $x_i^n$ is NOT nth power of $x_i$ :)

Comment: Ok. You can use this notation provided you warn.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sure.I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Clearly for every $i$ there exists $J(i)$ such that
$$\sum_{j=J(i)}^{\infty}p_{ij}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{J(i)}|x_j^n-x_j|<J(i)\frac{\varepsilon}{2J(i)}=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
for $n\geq N$ as You defined it. Thus
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}p_{ij}|x_j^n-x_j|\leq\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^{J(i)}|x_j^n-x_j|}_{<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}+\underbrace{\sum_{j=J(i)}^{\infty}p_{ij}}_{<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}<\varepsilon$$
for $n\geq N$. This way You proved
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}p_{ij}{x_j^n}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}p_{ij}{x_j}$$ for every $i$.